# Shapeless HList return type

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, implicit, shapeless

I am trying to incorporate a bit of shapeless into my code and am falling at an embarassingly early hurdle. In the example below, it seems that HCons-ing an undefined object to an HNil:

```
trait HasValue[A, B] {
  def get(a: A): B
  def getAll[L <: HList, O <: HList](a: A)(implicit ga: GetAll[A, L]): O = ga.getAll(a, HNil)
}

trait GetAll[A, B] {
  def getAll[L <: HList, O <: HList](a: A, l: L): O
}
implicit def getAllIfHasValue[A, B](implicit ev: HasValue[A, B]) = new GetAll[A, B] {
  def getAll[L <: HList, O <: HList](a: A, l: L): O = ev.get(a) :: l
}
```

and getting an error - `type mismatch: Found B :: L, Required O`.
I would have thought that, since `L` is itself an `HList`, `B :: L` should itself be an `HList` and therefore all should be well. But obviously not.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. `getAll` signature looks suspicious: it says that for every HList types `L` and `O` you can produce `O` based only on `L` and `A`. This function doesn't have reasonable implementations (other than returning `HNil` always). Perhaps you'd want to move `L` and `O` to the list of trait type parameters.

Comment: @simpadjo - Yes - I have not used a good example here. One thing which was slightly throwing me in the examples I was reading, was that people tend to use the syntax (when using HLists as either function arguments or return types) of, say, `def f[L <: HList]: L = 1 :: HNil`. It's not immediately obvious to me why the `L` type parameter is needed here. Why not simply `def f: HList = 1 :: HNil`?

Comment: `HList` type says nothing about the types of its element. `L` is supposed to carry information about elements as well.

Comment: @Chrisper By the way, `def f[L <: HList]: L = 1 :: HNil` is incorrect. This is as if I wrote `def f[A]: A = 1`. I guess you should think what type parametrers mean in Scala.

Comment: @Chrisper If you write that `1 :: HNil` has type `HList` you loose type-level information about `Int :: HNil`. `HList` is not better than `List[Any]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error is pretty clear

```
type mismatch;
 found   : B :: L
 required: O
```

`ev.get(a) :: l` has type `B :: L` but `O` is expected.

> I would have thought that, since `L` is itself an `HList`, `B :: L` should itself be an `HList` and therefore all should be well.

`B :: L` is an `HList`, indeed. The problem is that `B :: L` is not `O`.

And when you write the signature

```
def getAll[L <: HList, O <: HList](a: A, l: L): O = ???
```

this means, for any type `L <: HList` and **any type** `O <: HList`, having values `a: A` and `l: L` produce a value of type `O`. I guess that's not what you wanted.

Maybe you wanted to return a type `O` depending on types `A`, `B`. Then you can introduce a type parameter

```
trait GetAll[A, B] {
  type O
  def getAll[L <: HList](a: A, l: L): O
}
```

Or maybe you wanted to return a type `O` depending on types `A`, `B`, `L <: HList`. Then additionally you should transfer `L` to the trait level

```
trait GetAll[A, B, L <: HList] {
  type O
  def getAll(a: A, l: L): O
}
```

Comment: thanks - yes, I think I have been having some confusion about how type parameters work in these kind of contexts. The underlying problem (which my original example was a poor representation of) I have now figured out.